# Hello, can somebody help me making a checkbox to be mandatory in my shopify checkout page? I have dawn them

Tags: shopify

I have to make a required / mandatory checkbox so when my clients go to the cart page they have to agree with my terms and conditions before proceeding to the checkout page

I was able to put the checkbox right next to the "checkout" button but I cannot make it required

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have shopify-plus package in order to make changes inside checkout page. so when you will have shopify-plus admin access,

1. Go to storefront code editor(shopify's code editor)
2. Open `checkout.liquid` named layout and use jQuery to make condition that

   if ($('input[name=className]:checked')) {
   $('#id').show(); // show proceeding to the checkout HTML
   }